# Can you write down the fourier transform as follows? $F(\omega)^2=\left(\int \cos(\omega t) \right)^2 +\left(\int f(t) \sin(\omega t) \right)^2 $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Can you write down the fourier transform as follows?

$$  F(\omega)^2 = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \cos(\omega t) \right)^2  + \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \sin(\omega t) \right)^2 $$

If so how can you visualise this triangle and why is this true?

Comment: What triangle? If $f$ was real, the modulus square would be equal to the right hand side. Note also you have a typo in the title

Comment: No, that expression is not correct.